# Rails 5 - PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "application_records" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to set up a **new** Rails 5 application (ruby 2.3.1, rails 5.0.0.rc1) with postgresql, devise gems and it is failing to run `rails db:seed` due to following error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "application_records" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"application_records"'::r...
                                          ^
/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:88:in `async_exec'
/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:88:in `block in query'
/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:566:in `block in log'
/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:560:in `log'
/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:87:in `query'
/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:739:in `column_definitions'
/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:227:in `columns'
```

After much googling, I've realized that this has something to do with the [ApplicationRecord base class change in rails 5](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/12/28/application-record-in-rails-5.html). Clearly there's no table called `application_records` and so active_support shouldn't be looking for it. I have already checked that `app/models/application_record.rb` exists and has the right content. Also, the User model (which is the only model in my app currently) extends ApplicationRecord as expected:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

`rails db: migrate` runs fine, but `rails db:seed` chokes with the above error.

Can anyone shed some light on what might be causing this?

Contents of `application_record.rb`:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

Comment: What is the content of your `application_record.rb` file?

Comment: Added contents of application_record.rb to the question

Comment: Thanks. I created a sample 5.0 RC app but was not able to reproduce this issue. I would advice to open an issue on Rails issue tracker - https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/ -  with a sample application uploaded to Github which reproduces the issue. Tag me as @prathamesh-sonpatki on Github issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @PrathameshSonpatki. I have uploaded my project on github and filed a bug as you suggested: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25379. I've also found this workaround: If I add `self.table_name = 'users'` in my User model, everything works fine.

Answer (score 7):

The

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "application_records" does not exist
```

error also happens if you remove the line:

```
self.abstract_class = true
```

from `app/models/application_record.rb`

That line lets Rails know that this is not a model that should ever be persisted to the database, there's a good summary of Rails' abstract classes here: https://medium.com/@jeremy_96642/deep-rails-how-to-use-abstract-classes-6aee9b686e75

Comment: This was my issue. I had to downgrade my RoR app from 3 databases to 1 in order to deploy to Heroku. When doing that I got too ambitious in removing lines in the models and removed `self.abstract_class = true` from `app/models/application_record.rb`. Thank you @agbodike for this solution!

Answer (score 3):

Answering My own question, so it may help others running into similar issues.

As metioned by @PrathameshSonpatki on the [rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25379), this happens because [userstamp gem](https://github.com/lowjoel/activerecord-userstamp) injects relationships on `ActiveRecord::Base` rather than `ApplicationRecord`. (Note that userstamp gem isn't rails 5 compatible at the time of this writing).

If you have a gem not yet tested with rails 5 and you get an issue where active_support goes looking for a table called `application_records`, check if one of the gems you are using injects relationships on the `ActiveRecord::Base` class. Based on [this blog post](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/12/28/application-record-in-rails-5.html), the very purpose of `ApplicationRecord` is to avoid global injection of `ActiveRecord::Base`. Therefore you'd need to look for a version of such gem that is compatible with Rails 5 or patch such gem to inject the necessary behavior into `ApplicaitonRecord` instead of `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Comment: I wonder what is the best way to track down a gem which breaks our app. We have few hundreds and userstamp is not in there.

Comment: @Izap I have a gem called `gem_bench`, which allows you to grep through the source code of all gems bundled in a project, so you can look for things like that. https://github.com/pboling/gem_bench